Next.js Deployment Problem Using Docker buffering 1000MS MONGODB
Hey Guys i have problem after i deployment my project using dokcer
when i open site
Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information).
Digest: 3938613122
and her's the logs
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.2
  - Local:        http://localhost:3001
  - Network:      http://0.0.0.0:3001

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 177ms
MongoDB Connected
MongoDB Connected
MongooseError: Operation `tags.aggregate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
MongooseError: Operation `questions.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
MongooseError: Operation `tags.aggregate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  digest: '3938613122'
}
MongooseError: Operation `tags.aggregate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  digest: '3938613122'
}
MongoDB Connection Failed MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:875:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:826:11)
    at async o (/app/.next/server/chunks/253.js:1:44974)
    at async u (/app/.next/server/chunks/253.js:1:21972)
    at async j (/app/.next/server/app/(root)/(home)/page.js:1:13623) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
MongooseError: Operation `tags.aggregate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
MongooseError: Operation `questions.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
MongooseError: Operation `questions.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
MongooseError: Operation `tags.aggregate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  digest: '3938613122'
}
MongooseError: Operation `questions.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  digest: '132214018'
}


i try to deploy it in vercel and it's work 100% without any problem
but the problem in linux i don't know why i try mongodb atlas and configuration network accesses and mongodb docker image
but the problem the same
here is function connect db
export const connectDB = async () => {
  mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

  if (!process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
    return console.log("MISSING MONGODB_URL");
  }

  if (isConnected) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
      dbName: "code-stacker",
    });
    isConnected = true;
    console.log("MongoDB Connected");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("MongoDB Connection Failed", error);
  }
};


and here is one of the function the occur problem because of it
export async function getPopularTags() {
  try {
    await connectDB();
    const popularTags = await Tag.aggregate([
      { $project: { name: 1, numberOfQuestions: { $size: "$questions" } } },
      { $sort: { numberOfQuestions: -1 } },
      { $limit: 5 },
    ]);
    return popularTags;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}


I'M NOT UNDERSTANDING WHY IT'S WORK IN VERCEL AND LOCAL USING MONGO ATLAS BUT IN MY UBUNTU LINUX DEPLOY USING DOCKER NOT WORK AND DOCKER IMAGE ALSO
DockerFile
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3001

ENV PORT 3001

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0" node server.js


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Setup Mongodb using docker compose side by side with next.js project.
